# Initialize object and create it later depending on value in if statement

Tags: java, c++

I have Java code similar to this with many if-else statements:

```
if(...){
     Object1 obj = new Object1();
     String text = obj.getString();
     int number = obj.getInt();
     //do something

}else if (...){
     Object2 obj = new Object2();
     String text = obj.getString();
     int number = obj.getInt();
     //do something
...
```

is it possible, somehow, to write code in this way:

```
<something> obj;  //<- ?

if(..)
     obj = new Object1;
else if(..)
     obj = new Object2;
...
String text = obj.getString();
int number = obj.getInt();
//do something
```

thanks for help.

PS:You can write solution in C++; I'll figure it out for java

PS(2):Sorry for bad English - it's not my primary language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to above would be an interface

```
public interface Ibase {
  String getString();
  int getInt();
}
```

which your two objects would then implement that interface ensuring they have those methods available.

```
public class Object1 implements IBase {
 public String getString() {
   return "string";
 }

 public int getInt() {
   return 0;
 }
}
```

then like above can use

```
IBase object = null
if(option)
  object = new Object1()
else
 object = new Object2();

object.getString();
object.getInt();
```

think of interface like a contract that the sub classes have to abide by.

Comment: nice, I'll try ... so there is no need to cast methods/object like: String text = (cast) object.getString() ?

Comment: no it knows based on the interface that `getString()` will return a String.

Answer (score 3):

In both, you'll need a base class. For both, you can initially have a `NULL` reference (Java) or pointer (C++), which you then set:

```
BaseObject* pBase = NULL;
if (...)
     pBase = new Object1;
else
     pBase = new Object2;
```

In Java it wouldn't be that different (missing asterix and `null` instead of `NULL`);

Comment: thanks for answer, I was afraid that another class is necessary :/

Comment: @SanjinKurelić in Java, that's easy because of the base `Object` (although you might need a new base class, depending on the requirements), in C++ a generic base doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object obj = null;
if(..)
     obj = new Object1();
else if(..)
     obj = new Object2();
```

However, be aware that for the compiler, `obj` is of type `Object`. You can't apply methods specific to `Object1` or `Object2` without down-casting.

Comment: so when I call method, I need to write int number = (Object1) obj.getInt();

Comment: @SanjinKurelić yes, that's true. You could also define a common interface of Object1 and Object2, see the answer of AbstractChaos